# Where to enable zip64 extension in build.gradle.kts?

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I am working on a ktor multiplatform application.

While the application is running continuously, I come across an error message that says

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> - What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':jvmJar'.
>   archive's size exceeds the limit of 4GByte.
>   To build this archive, please enable the zip64 extension.
>   See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip:

How and where to enable the zip64 extension?The version of gradle that I am using is 7.3.3

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a `Jar` task?
Say you use ShadowJar, then the configuration would look like:

```
tasks.shadowJar {
    setProperty("zip64", true)

    // other shadow jar config
}
```

Comment: zip64 true in gradle or zip64.set(true) will say   
  zip64.set(true)
             ^ Unresolved reference: zip64

Comment: Yes, that's why you should use the setProperty() function

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin versionvof @jolan-rensen

```
tasks.withType<ShadowJar> { isZip64 = true }
```

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
tasks {
    shadowJar {
        isZip64 = true
    }
}
```